# how to attach private data to libxml2 or gdome dom tree

Tags: c++, libxml2

I'd like to hang some private data (void*) off of nodes in a DOM tree using the libxml2 or gdome APIs.  Looking through the (rather sparse) api docs, it seems like the libxml2 nodes might have a member for user data (_private, on almost every object), but I didn't see any api calls for manipulating this.

Comment: I think adding userdata is included in DOM level 3, gdome is level 2. Maybe you can use a DOM level 3 library (like xerces) ? Then userdata is possible and the library can handle the lifetime of your data.

Answer (score 1):

As the xmlNode is a struct you can directly access the `void* _private` members.

```
xmlNode * ePtr = ...;
ePtr->_private = ...;
```

But I can't find any documentation saying that field is for custom user data. So I'd avoid that approach.

Instead I'd use a separate metadata store, something like `std::map<xmlNode*, void*>` would do. (I'd use something  a little more type-safe than `void*` but hopefully you get the idea)

The biggest problem that I see (in both cases) is that you need to be careful about the lifetime of the metadata you associate. I can see no way to be notified of the destruction of a node ... which may lead to all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says *For user data, libxml won't touch it* about `_private`, but my recollection is that it is meant for things like libxml2 language bindings (e.g. [xmlwrapp](https://github.com/vslavik/xmlwrapp) uses it for that purpose), not for user code.